# Theorem/Definition/... with individual numbering

Tags: numbering, theorems, definition, mathematics

I would like to give the theorem/lemma/definition/... environment an *individual* number. For example:

> 1 Section
>
> Theorem **20.1.**  (XXX) ...
>   Definiton **21.2.1.**: ...

Here is the "20.1." and "21.2.1" individual numbers that I would add/pass to the theorem/definition environment. The goal is an **independent** numbering from the previous theorem, lemma, etc.  How can I implement this?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. What is 20 and 1 in this case and similar for 21, 2 and 1.

Comment: So you would like to number the theorems manually each time a theorem environment is called?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: What's the reason for manual numbering?

Comment: I am studying mathematics and I copy the theorems, definitions, etc. from the math script; quasi as a collection. The numbering is continued by remarks and examples, but they do not interest me. In order to be able to refer to what is written in the script, I would like to insert the original numbering. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two generic environments and assign manually the numbers.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{innerthm}{\innerthmname}
\newcommand{\innerthmname}{}% initialize
\newenvironment{statement}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\innerthmname}{#1}\innerthm}
 {\endinnerthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{innerdfn}{\innerthmname}
\newenvironment{upstatement}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\innerthmname}{#1}\innerdfn}
 {\endinnerdfn}

\begin{document}

\begin{statement}{Theorem 20.1}[XXX]
Some text.
\end{statement}

\begin{statement}{Lemma 15.2}
Some text.
\end{statement}

\begin{upstatement}{Definition 20.1.2}
Some text.
\end{upstatement}

\end{document}
```

[image]